# Win32 Prevent Process from Seeing or Closing Processes from other sessions

Tags: windows, winapi

When running under Citrix or RDP as an admin, I can see, terminate or otherwise manipulate processes created by other users, or in other sessions.  Admins need to be able to do this from time to time so I can't remove that capability from Admin logins, but I'd like to restrict it on certain processes.

Is there a way to change the security and/or privileges of the current process or a process I launch, so that it can no longer see or otherwise manipulate other user's processes?  I'd be happy to either change the rights of the currently executing process (which is mine), or launch my process using some method that denies the privilege to the target executable.  It's the inverse of *Run as Admin*.

I thought that [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be the key, but I can't seem to find any privileges to remove that relate to seeing other users' processes in the [Privilege Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) list.

[CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with an appropriate lpSecurityDescriptor seems like it might do the trick, but I haven't been able to find a good example of the security descriptor, or anything that relates to other users' processes.

Anyone know the secret sauce?  Thanks

Comment: I haven't double-checked this, but I would imagine that membership of the Administrators group is enough to give you access to most processes.  SeDebugPrivilege also gives such access, and the backup and restore privileges may do so.  Note that a non-elevated process will not have any of these, and so shouldn't have access to other user's processes; so the most obvious answer is "don't run that process elevated".  (Note that `lpSecurityDescriptor` won't help; that controls access *to* the new process, not what access the new process has.)

Comment: The ability to terminate a process is controlled by the `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access control mask. (As @HarryJohnston noted, there are some privileges that give you terminate-equivalence. For example, if you have debug privilege, you can just debug the program and make it jump to `TerminateProcess`.)

Comment: Thanks, those are helpful.  PROCESS_TERMINATE doesn't help me because I have to be able to be able to terminate my own processes, just not others.  I do think the run without elevated privileges route is what I'll have to do.